# Issue using FIFOs (pipes) with integers and a string

Tags: c

I am having an issue in my program where I need to bring a string from client to server and the server will then use that string to create a private FIFO. However when I type a name when prompted on client and then try to continue on server, it errors out saying: no file or directory exists.

Also, I do not understand how to move integers from the server to the client because the write() method does not work (seems to only work with chars and strings).

Clientside:

```
main (void)
{
  int fda;  // to write to server
  int fdb;  // to read response from server
  int mem_req[1];   // buffer holds a #
  char outchar[7];  // server puts string here
  char pfifo_name[10];

  memset(mem_req,0,1); 
  memset(outchar,0,7); 
  memset(pfifo_name,0,10);

  printf("\nClient: Please enter a private FIFO name (less than 10 chars): ");
  scanf("%s", &pfifo_name);

  printf("\nClient: Please enter a memory request number: ");
  scanf("%d", &mem_req);

  if((fda=open("FIFO1", O_WRONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to write");

  if((fdb=open(pfifo_name, O_RDONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to read");




  write(fda, mem_req, 1);
  write(fda, pfifo_name, 10);
  printf("\nClient: Pfifo and memory request sent to server ");
  read(fdb, outchar, 7);
  printf("\nClient: received from server %s", outchar);

  close(fda);
  close(fdb);

  printf ("\nall done!\n");
```

Serverside:

```
     main (void)
{
  int fda;  // to read from client
  int fdb;  // to write to client
  int finish;   // lets me know that client is done
  int i;    // because C needs this defined as int
  int fr_size; // frame size for memory management
  int temp_mem;
  int n_frame = 0;
  int o_frame = 0;
  int n_byte = 0;
  int o_byte = 0;
  int fr_num = 0;
  int byte_num;

  char mem_req[1];  // buffer holds a character
  char outchar[7];  // server puts string here
  char pfifo_name[10]; //client provides server a private fifo name

  memset(mem_req,0,1); 
  memset(outchar,0,7); 
  memset(pfifo_name,0,10);

  printf("\nServer: Please enter a desired frame(page) size: ");
  scanf("%d", &fr_size);
  read(fda, pfifo_name, 10);
  /* Create the fifos and open them  */
  if ((mkfifo("FIFO1",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
    {
    perror("cant create FIFO1");
    exit(-1);
    }

   if ((mkfifo(pfifo_name,0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
    {
    perror("cant create private fifo");
    exit(-1);
    }

  if((fda=open("FIFO1", O_RDONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to read");

  if((fdb=open(pfifo_name, O_WRONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to write");



  printf("\nServer: just got memeory request: ,%d", mem_req[0]);

  temp_mem = mem_req[0];

  n_frame = temp_mem/fr_size; // number of frames required for job
  n_byte = temp_mem - (n_frame * fr_size); // ending byte location

  write(fdb, &o_frame, sizeof(o_frame)); // output frame start location
  printf("\nServer: Frame start location sent");

  write(fdb, &o_byte, sizeof(o_byte));
  printf("\nServer: Byte start location sent");

  write(fdb, &n_frame, sizeof(n_frame));
  printf("\nServer: Frame end location sent");

  write (fdb, &n_byte, sizeof(n_byte));
  printf("\nServer: Byte end location sent");

  finish=read(fda, pfifo_name, 10);     //read the character
```

When the compiler gets to mkfifo(pfifo_name,0666)<0 on server, it errors out the following:

"cant create private fifo: no such file or directory exists"

i also receive errors from all 4 write statements on server (trying to pass an integer over the pipe and it is not working)

Comment: regarding lines like: `memset(mem_req,0,1);`   the number `0` is (for a 32bit architecture) 0x00000000.   What you actually want is a single byte `0x00` (aka `'\0'`)   While implicit conversion will probably save you,  it is best to indicate what you actually want.  Suggest: `memset( mem_req, '\0', 1 );`  Note: appropriate horizontal spacing greatly improves readability.

Comment: the client side code seems to be missing one or more lines at the end.  Similar considerations exist for the server side code.  Suggest, when posting a question about a run time problem, post code that cleanly compiles, that show the problem.  Be sure to include which header files are #include'd so we do not have to guess.

Comment: NOTE; a 2 space char indent is not wide enough to show when using variable width fonts.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level.

Comment: NOTE: the function `main()` when using a OS, always has the return type of `int`,

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) Please use meaningful variable names that indicate content or usage or both. 2) the posted code contains lots of 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest #define statements or an enum to give those numbers meaningful names and use those meaningful names throughout the code.  'magic' numbers like: 7,10.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the `%s` format specifier, always include a length modifier (that is 1 less than the input buffer length) to avoid overflowing the input buffer (such overflow is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: before opening a fifo, the fifo must be created, with something like `mkfifo()`

Comment: Normally, a client and server are on separate computers. (and even if on the same computer).  Communication is via a `socket` not a `fifo`.  Infact, a fifo cannot communicate beyond the current computer.  In the posted code, there seems to be two way communication, so two fifo's are needed.  Note: fifos are persistent (endure after program exits) so when designing the call to `mkfifo()` you will need to allow for that scenario.

Comment: the syntax for the `write()` function is: `ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);`.  Which means the third parameter is the number of bytes to be written.  This line: `write(fd_out, mem_req, 1);` is trying to writ an integer.  Depending on the underlying architecture, a integer could be anywhere from 1 (a 16bit microprocessor) to 8 (a 64bit architecture).  The third parameter is only going to write 1 byte.  What will be in that byte?  That depends on if the architecture is Big or Little Endian.

Comment: (cont)  (suggest using `sprintf()` to convert to a string and sending that string) however, `write(fd_out, mem_req, sizeof(int));` would send the value as a binary item.

Comment: in the server, this line: `read(fda, pfifo_name, 10);` will NEVER read a fifo/pipe.   first, that `fifo` has to be created, then the `fifo` has to be opened for read,  And take into account (if on a linux system) that the `umask` environment variable also is involved in the resulting file permissions

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I am rather new to pipes and named pipes and I was trying to put something together real quick and it made no sense. This has helped my understanding. I accidentally placed the read before the initialization and didn't notice it for a while. After realizing how poorly I did this program, I went back and changed to a struct for data transfering and pid() for safer FIFO naming (since there is no way another client would have the same process ID, but CAN have the same user inputted ID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the server:

```
read(fda, pfifo_name, 10);
```

This fails because `fda` doesn't contain a valid file descriptor, because it was never initialized.

As a result, nothing gets read into `pfifo_name`, so it holds only 0 bytes (because of the previous call to `memset`), i.e. an empty string. Then you pass this to `open`, which tries to open a file with a blank name, which is not valid.

Comment: @tcmike What exactly did you move?

Comment: I got rid of the memset stuff altogether and moved the read(fda, pfifo_name, 10) to after mkfifo and the open statement for FIFO1 (also moved the pfifo mkfifo and open to be below the read statement that contains the pfifo name). Unfortunately, after doing this, I still was unable to create that private FIFO with that string name. None of the values were making it serverside and so this tells me there is an issue with the FIFO still. Or that I should instead make a struct to carry over both the memory request integer AND the private FIFO name to the server